# Problema con Matriz

Tags: java, matrices

verán estoy haciendo un programa en el que me pide los elementos de una matriz y este me los regresa, el punto es que al ejecutarlo me regresa el ultimo valor que ingrese repetido. Ejemplo si asigno una matriz de 2x2 me pide los 4 valores pero solo me regresa el ultimo valor repetido 4 veces, he estado intentando corregirlo pero no lo he conseguido. Se que al codigo le faltan algunas cosas para que quede bien.

```
public class Suma{
private int[][] arreglo;
private int[][] arreglo1;
private int elemento;
private int elemento1;

public Suma(int elemento, int elemento1){
arreglo = new int[elemento][elemento1];
arreglo1 = new int[elemento][elemento1];
}


public boolean setElemento(int valor){
boolean respuesta = false;
for(int x=0; x<arreglo.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<arreglo[x].length; y++){
arreglo[x][y] = valor;
respuesta = true;
  }
 }return respuesta;
}



public boolean setElemento1(int valor1){
boolean respuesta1 = false;
for(int x=0; x<arreglo1.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<arreglo1[x].length; y++){
arreglo1[x][y] = valor1;
respuesta1 = true;
  }
 }return respuesta1;
}

public String stoString(){
String elementos = " ";
String elementos1 = " ";
for(int x=0; x<arreglo.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<arreglo[x].length; y++){
elementos = elementos + " " + arreglo1[x][y];

}
System.out.println("\n ");
}
return elementos;
}


public String toString(){
String elementos = " ";
String elementos1 = " ";
for(int x=0; x<arreglo.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<arreglo[x].length; y++){
elementos = elementos + " " + arreglo[x][y];
}
}
return elementos;
}

}
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sumas{
public static void main(String []args){

Suma Sumas;
int nfilas, ncolumnas;
int numero, numero1;

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Dame el numero de filas: ");
nfilas = teclado.nextInt();
System.out.println("Dame el numero de columnas: ");
ncolumnas = teclado.nextInt();
Sumas = new Suma(nfilas, ncolumnas);



for(int x=0; x<nfilas; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<ncolumnas; y++){
    System.out.println("Dame el " + x +","+ y + "valor de la primera matriz");
    numero = teclado.nextInt();
    Sumas.setElemento(numero);
    }
}



for(int x=0; x<nfilas; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<ncolumnas; y++){
    System.out.println("Dame el " + x +","+ y + "valor de la segunada matriz");
    numero1 = teclado.nextInt();
    Sumas.setElemento1(numero1);
    }
}



System.out.println("Los elementos ingresados son: " + Sumas.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

primero que todo tienes un error de logica de programacion al adicionar los elementos a las matrices. Con tu logica siempre se adiciona el último elemento ingresado, en todos los campos de la matriz.

```
public boolean setElemento(int valor){
    boolean respuesta = false;
    //con el doble for se adiciona el contenido de valor en toda la matriz, cosa que no se quiere
    for(int x=0; x<arreglo.length; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<arreglo[x].length; y++){
            arreglo[x][y] = valor;
            respuesta = true;
        }
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

La solución es que envies la posición donde deseas guardar el valor enviado a setElemento así:

En la clase Sumas:

```
for (int x = 0; x < nfilas; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < ncolumnas; y++) {
        System.out.println("Dame el " + x + "," + y + "valor de la primera matriz");
        numero = teclado.nextInt();
        Sumas.setElemento(numero, x, y);
    }
}
```

En la clase Suma:

```
public boolean setElemento(int valor, int x, int y) {
    arreglo[x][y] = valor;
    return true;
}
```

Claramente, hay que realizar el mismo procedimiento para el segundo vector.